# JSSOR - Transition when bullets or arrows clicked

Tags: jssor

I'd like to know if there is a way to use the transition I have chosen when I click the bullets or the arrays? Because the effect only applies when I let it automatically slide (slideshow mode)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Jssor support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key feature of Jssor Slider is TOUCH SWIPE by Finger/Mouse on mobile/desktop.
So it should move when touched instead of play transition.

If you are interested, please wait for **Jssor Slideo**, which is under development.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm very interested in this functionality so i am impatient to discover Jssor Slideo  Good luck for the development.