# Jssor slider manual transition trigger

Tags: slider, slideshow, jssor

Is it possible to have manual trigger for transitions from one slide to another.

If I use $JssorArrowNavigator$, it does slide to next/previous, but without transitions.

Adding custom actions $PlayTo, $GoTo, $Next also just slides to next, but without transition.

$Play starts the slideshow with the transitions but there is some initial lag of ~10s.

Comment: Ok, I see now that is currently not supported. For anyone looking for the same thing, here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23747621/jssor-transition-when-bullets-or-arrows-clicked

Answer (score 0):

Slideshow transition plays only for 'auto play'.

While auto play, you can assign transition for specific slide.

```
function SlideParkEventHandler(slideIndex, fromIndex)
{
    if(slideIndex == 0)
    {
        jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{transition_code1}]);
    }
    else if(slideIndex == 1)
    {
        jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{transition_code2}]);
    }
    else
    {
        jssor_slider1.$SetSlideshowTransitions([{transition_code3}, {transition_code4}, ...]);
    }
}

jssor_slider1.$On($JssorSlider$.$EVT_PARK, SlideParkEventHandler);
```